# CAS username field value to be manually added to the existing user on import?

Tags: 8, users, importing-exporting

I installed the CAS module on a Drupal 8 site, and it is working fine. For new users, it auto-registers the user with cas_username, but I would like to import the cas_username manually for the existing Drupal 8 user.

I also tried importing users in CSV format; I have been able to add the $account(row[0],row[1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261232)), but for the CAS username import, i don't know how to import it, and in which field is stored.

```
'uid' => NULL,
'name' => $username,
'field_first_name' => row[0],
'field_last_name' => $row[1],
'pass' => $username,
'mail' => $row[2],
'status' => 1,
'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
'roles' => array_values($config['roles']),
```

I tried [Managing CAS username](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261232); the suggestion given is for Drupal 7, but the same method doesn't work for Drupal 8.

How do I import the CAS username in CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution for the CAS_username import in CSV method. The method of db_insert in (authmap) table, which dynamically insert the CAS_username in respective field.

The authmap table is present in external authentication module.

```
    db_insert('authmap')
    ->fields(array(
     'uid' => $uid,
     'provider' => 'cas',
     'authname' => $row[0],
     'data' => 'N;',
     ))
    ->execute();
```

So this is the method, i dynamically update the CAS_username using CSV. If any suggestions or update in that. Kindly Prescribe it.